# Apache and 302 redirect issues

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to temporary bypass a 302 browser redirect by configuring Apache to rewrite all incoming HTTP requests from an external to an internal address before proxy-ing the request to a tomcat server listening on localhost. Reason being that the internal address is not exposed to the user environment. Ultimately the problem should be solved by reconfiguring the application to not redirect the initial browser request to an internal URL for authentication (the OPENAM XUI login page) but for now a workaround is needed.

My first attempt to achieve this was by using the standard ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives but it seems that a 302 redirect request causes the client to break out of the proxy. My hope is now that that with help of the mod_rewrite engine I can make the redirect request not happening by configuring an internal-to-external http-request "translator". Unfortunately all my attempts to achieve such a setup have failed.

Question: is it possible to rewrite all incoming http requests from "https://external.app-server.com/app1/*" to "https://internal.app-server.com/app1/*" **before** the request is proxied to a localhost tomcat instance?

My currrently (not working) Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^https://internal\.app-server\.com  
RewriteRule "^/app1(.\*)" http://localhost:8080/app1$1  
RewriteRule "^/openam(.\*)" https://localhost:8081/openam$1  

SSLProxyEngine on  
ProxyPreserveHost off  
# ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1/  
ProxyPassReverse /app1  http://localhost:8080/app1/  
# ProxyPass /openam http://localhost:8081/openam  
ProxyPassReverse /openam http://localhost:8081/openam
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 VirtualHost configurations.

Scenario:

- users connect to https://external.example.com/app1
- this proxies to https://internal.example.com/app1
- this proxies to Tomcat at localhost:PORT

Your Apache configuration could look like:

```
Listen 443

# Responds to external.example.com requests
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName external.example.com
    CustomLog "logs/external.access.log" common
    ErrorLog "logs/external.error.log"
    LogLevel debug
    
    # TODO SSL directives

    ProxyPass "/app1" "https://internal.example.com:8080/app1"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app1" "https://internal.example.com:8080/app1"
</VirtualHost>

# Responds to internal.example.com requests
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName internal.example.com
    CustomLog "logs/internal.access.log" common
    ErrorLog "logs/internal.error.log"
    LogLevel debug

    # TODO SSL directives

    ProxyPass "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```

- Note: modify the port with the real Tomcat port you are using (instead of 8080).
- Note 2: split your logs, it makes debugging must easier.
- Note 3:`&nbsp;` can be used in HTML files, not apache configuration.
- Note 4: to comment out a configuration line, put `#`.  I do not know what `\#` does...

---

**OR**

If the server that responds to external.example.com and internal.example.com is the same, you can proxy both to tomcat directly.

You would do it like this:

```
Listen 443

# Responds to external.example.com requests
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName external.example.com
    CustomLog "logs/external.access.log" common
    ErrorLog "logs/external.error.log"
    LogLevel debug
    
    # TODO SSL directives

    ProxyPass "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
</VirtualHost>

# Responds to internal.example.com requests
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName internal.example.com
    CustomLog "logs/internal.access.log" common
    ErrorLog "logs/internal.error.log"
    LogLevel debug

    # TODO SSL directives

    ProxyPass "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app1" "http://localhost:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example configuration. I tried it but unfortunately the browser redirect remains. The objective is for the server to (silently) rewrite the incoming external http requests before sending each request to the reverse proxy (proxypass). So, not redirect the browser to the internal-address because that is being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Ha, so you do not want a redirect then.  You need to proxy twice.  Once external to internal, then internal to tomcat.  Or you could (if allowed by your FW infrastructure) proxy external directly to tomcat.  "silently rewrite" does not exist, a rewrite will always return to the browser.  Edit coming up...